# How trace.json can be used in calculating performance metrics

Tags: groovy, unetstack

I am implementing an `energy-based routing` protocol. I want to analyze the protocol performance using the `trace.json` file. I wanted to know Whether `trace.json` has sufficient information to calculate network performance metrics like the end-to-end delay, throughput, etc. If yes, how can I use `trace.json` in calculating performance metrics?

Comment: `trace.json` has timing information about datagrams at all levels of the network stack. This should typically be sufficient to compute throughput, delays, etc. If there is specific information that you're looking for, and can't find in the file, please refine your question to clearly state what information you're looking for.

Comment: When multiple datagrams are sent from a source or when multiple sources send datagrams to a sink. In this case How to identify individual datagrams? which field to consider in trace.json to uniquely identify the datagrams?

Comment: Take a look at https://blog.unetstack.net/whats-new-in-UnetStack-3.3 for more information on `trace.json`. The `threadID` attribute is performa what you're looking for to uniquely identify all messages associated with a originating datagram.